# Hacker caused my website to display ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: ubuntu, web-application-security

The hacker has done something that I have not been able to resolve. My website got taken down, and all I get now is an error in my browser that says, "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

**Stuff I have tried to fix the problem:**

1. Verified the right ports are open in the Digital Ocean firewall
2. Verified the right ports are open in the UFW firewall
3. Apache is running and listening to port 80
4. DNS records are in order
5. Checked settings for virtual host configuration
6. Made a simple .html page with Hello World, incase this connection error was due to DB
7. Tried a non-existent webpage and did NOT get a 404 error
8. curl http://localhost returned correctly the homepage html

What else could it possibly be? Please point me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: I've never used DigitalOcean, but maybe they turned on a requirement for HTTPS?  If not that, search on the error to find other articles, guides, SO posts.  You did contact DigitalOcean support too, right?  If this is a WordPress site you might also be better off moving to someone that takes care of security for you like WPEngine.